# Avast Mobile Security reports suspicious app activity for Ionic app

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have created an Android app using the Ionic framework. The purpose of app is to fetch data from a website using [import.io](https://www.import.io/) and display in the app, however my mobile antivirus is showing me suspicious app activity warning.

```
Avast Mobile Security
Suspicious app activity.
Application_Name has been reported as a Suspicious app.
APK:CloudRep[susp]
```

kindly help me.

Comment: Could you give us more information? What kind of application are you building? What libraries does it use? It could be that you are using something or fetching data from a website that Avast considers suspicious.

Comment: Fetching news & events from university' notice board here is a link http://www.vu.edu.pk/News/NewsList.aspx

Comment: Plugins are: cordova-plugin-console, cordova-plugin-device, cordova-plugin-inappbrowser, cordova-plugin-splashscreen, cordova-plugin-statusbar, cordova-plugin-whitelist, ionic-plugin-keyboard, phonegap-plugin-push

Comment: The only thing I could find was this (https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/313), but that plugin is not in the list you posted, are there perhaps some dependencies you missed?

Comment: No, nothing else I used for it.

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of the application from 'Application_Name' to something else? Or is that a placeholder you placed to hide the name of your app?

Comment: Yes, I also try to change the name but same behavior on different names.

Comment: I am facing the same issue now. Has anyone found the main cause of this issue? I am just making some http calls to get data.

Comment: did you solved your problem? can you share with us how you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of error usually happens for apps installed through means, outside of the Google Play Store (e.g. by installing an APK directly from the SD card or by deploying and installing the APK through your Android Studio IDE using the Run command - which typically happens during the application development process).

So if you are the developer of the app, testing it on your real device or you trust the application's source completely, you should be fine. Otherwise, I wouldn't install that app.